# I am really new at coding and I am coding in lua a script for a part, I want the color to change every second

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local color = 1
while color < 5 do
game.Workspace.Part_multicolor.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
wait(1)
game.Workspace.Part_multicolor.BrickColor = BrickColor.Blue()
end
```

This is the code, I put a variable that its value its 1, then i put a loop that repeats forever and change between red and blue each second.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the color change every seconds you need one more "wait(1)"

```
local color = 1
while color < 5 do
 game.Workspace.Part_multicolor.BrickColor = BrickColor.Red()
 wait(1)
 game.Workspace.Part_multicolor.BrickColor = BrickColor.Blue()
 wait(1) --here add a wait(1)
end
```

the loop will wait 1 seconds after each change

Comment: Thank you!! I've been a lot of time for this